# How to properly redirect to new template using uuid as url slug in view

Tags: django

I have the following source template which renders the uuid of model `Pollers` as a hidden `<a>` tag to redirect the user to this item rendered in a fresh new template upon user click.

```
<div class="poller-wrapper">
  <a class="hidden_poller_id" href="/poller/{{ poller.poller_id }}">

  <div class="poller-text">{{ poller.poller_text }}</div>

[...]
```

The url mapping looks like follows:

```
urlpatterns = [

    # Main overview of recent pollers
    path('pollboard/', pollboard, name='pollboard'),

    # Redirect url to single Poller
    path('poller/<uuid:poller_id>', single_poller, name='single_poller'),

]
```

View

```
def single_poller(request):
    return render(request, 'pollboard/single_poller.html')
```

Right now I get the following error and I'm not sure why it doesn't redirect properly:

> TypeError at /poller/d251ce80-1d0d-41c4-a096-c12bdd2399f8
> single_poller() got an unexpected keyword argument 'poller_id'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your view should take the value for `poller_id` URL parameter, so:

```
#                            ↓ value matched by <uuid:poller_id>
def single_poller(request, poller_id):
    return render(request, 'pollboard/single_poller.html')
```

You can use this for example to fetch the related `Poller` object, and pass items as context to the `render(…)` call.